# Grpc service class as Singleton in Grpc.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-dotnet, grpc-c#

By default Asp.Net Core makes Grpc service class as scoped to handle multithreading of concurrent web requests. But, still we can make Grpc service class as Singleton inside ConfigureServices()

`services.AddSingleton<GreeterService>`

I am doing it because, I want to initiate my Grpc client calls from the Grpc service itself, that I want to do only at once. Here, both Grpc service and clients are executed as a single process within a single project.
`GrpcServices="both"`

But, multiple copies of the same project(Grpc service and client as embedded) can co-exist to replicate primary and standby nodes scenarios, where in each node will have its own single Grpc service and Grpc client. Will it cause any problems/performance issues for multithreading use cases, as each Grpc service node can get multiple Grpc client calls from other nodes in parallel, and where each Http2 request gets one thread to execute?